# Discard duplicate element in C array / Going out of array boundary

Tags: c, arrays

The below code discard duplicate elements in an array.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int arr[5] = {1,2,2,3,5};
    int i, j, k, size = 5;


    printf("\nArray with Unique list  : ");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < size;) {
            if (arr[j] == arr[i]) {
                for (k = j; k < size; k++) {
                    arr[k] = arr[k + 1];  //line in question
                }
                size--;
            } else
                j++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

In the line in question above. When `k = 4`, the right side of `arr[k] = arr[k + 1];` will go outside of array boundary.

My question is that is `arr[4] = arr[5];` valid? And why?

Added question:

If it is invalid why it works?

Code source: http://www.c4learn.com/c-programs/to-delete-duplicate-elements-in-array.html

Comment: `arr[5]` is invalid, because the array index is out of bounds. It's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Why does it work: Undefined behaviour includes anything from "apparently working fine" to "formatting your hard disk".

Comment: `If it is invalid why it works?`...well, technically, you can shoot your foot, but will you? If you know it's invalid, you never know it "works". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.My question is that is arr[4] = arr[5]; valid? And why?**
it's invalid because of errors : `array access out of bound`.

**2.If it is invalid why it works?**
you are dereferencing a value at some place like `a[5] = *(a+5)` which will give you some value here if OS allows you to access that area it will run otherwise it will crash so the behaviour is undefined if it is a restricted area in memory definitely crash will occur.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is that is arr[4] = arr[5]; valid? And why?

It's invalid due to the exact reason you pointed out: out-of-bound array access.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined behavior as you go out of boundary.
You have no guarantee to where your array sits, you might try write to
a place you have no permission to. Hence, you can't tell what will exactly happen.